# Laravel model relationship belongsTo with associate() gives infinite loop toArray()

Tags: php, laravel, model, relationship

I hope someone may help me with the issue I have for a long time, but only now I'm posting it.

The project I'm working on uses models with nested relationships. Just to simplify the context of the issue, let's imagine a parent with many children model relation: `hasMany` and `belongsTo`.

I usually create new instances and fill the properties then I relate them by hand using `setRelation()` and `associate()` methods (because I like to retrieve the relationships using parent-to-child and child-to-parent methods).
But infinite loops arises after I call `toArray()` (among many other model methods that traverse its relations).

The question is: Am I doing the right thing caling `setRelation` and `associate` for model relationship? If not, how would I retrieve `$model->children()`/`$model->parent()` relation?

**I'm using Laravel Framework 7.14.1 with PHPUnit 8.5.5 and PHP 7.4.4 (cli)**

Here a Unit test:

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Unit;

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Team extends Model {
    protected $fillable = ['name'];
    public function players()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Player::class);
    }
}

class Player extends Model {
    protected $fillable = ['name'];
    public function team()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Team::class);
    }
}

class CircularReferencesTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testCircularReference(): void
    {
        // new instances
        $team = app(Team::class)->fill(['name' => 'team name']);
        $player = app(Player::class)->fill(['name' => 'player name']);
        // set relations
        $team->setRelation('players', collect([$player]));
        $player->team()->associate($team);

        dd($team->toArray(), $player->toArray());  // ERROR: Segmentation fault (core dumped).
        // dd($team->push());  // push calls save() method recursively @see https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#the-push-method
        dd($team, $player);
    }
}
```

**I'm calling by:**
`./vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit --stop-on-failure --colors=always ./tests/Unit/CircularReferencesTest.php`

Comment: I don't think you need to ```setRelation``` in your case. In your models you could do ```return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Player')``` and ```return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Team')```. This will automatically bind the teams and players by their id if you have an ```id``` column in each table. Now, you will be able to retrieve your players from your team like this: ```$team->players```. It will return you a collection of the players in this team. Same thing for the other way around.

Comment: I understand that I would not need the set the relationship by hand when fetching data from a database, but in my case, I'm working with json/xml/csv files, so the data came from these files and go to the model, then (may or not) go to a database.

Comment: Maybe take a look at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31067642/laravel-5-eloquent-tojson-toarray-causes-strange-segmentation-faults

Comment: Thanks @ettdro for your reply. But I imagine what he did was creating another instance of the same class, so it breaks the circular reference and no segmentation faults occurs anymore. But I think thats not the proper way to deal with it, since the related model could have own properties set that the new instance does not have

Answer (score 0):

according to [this](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/21990#issuecomment-342704642)

you can't create a relationship between 2 models that are not already represented in the database.

at least  one of the models must be saved in advance, in order to create the relationship.

this is the first issue in your code ...

---

second one:
setting relation of one side is more than enough.. why you set the relation from the other side?

i mean:

one of those two line is enough:

```
 $team->setRelation('players', collect([$player]));
 $player->team()->associate($team);
```

i prefer using 'associate' method is more clearer ...

Comment: Thanks for your answer @OMR you said >"at least one of the models must be saved in advance, in order to create the relationship" I disagree with your observation since models can be related to each other using the correct methods provided by the framework/library. Furthermore, models should be database agnostic and must work even if no database is provided by the application/project. In my case, I'm working with raw text files, reading its content, hydrating models then transforming it to another output.

Comment: > "setting relation of one side is more than enough.. why you set the relation from the other side" I set relations on both sides just for the ease to "navigate" through models relationships. If no relation is set to the children, getting his parent would be a very difficult task.